# How can I export Android Play Open Beta feedback?

Tags: google-play, beta

I have an open beta on Android Play Store, and I can see feedback from it, but I can't see how to export that feedback.

I know how to download Play reviews from Download reports, but I don't see any beta feedback there.

Is there an API for downloading the Open Beta feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no official support for downloading this from Google, but:

1. Browse to Play Console > Ratings and Reviews > Testing Feedback
2. Use the Developer Tools > Network to find https://playconsolehealth-pa.clients6.google.com/.../reviews?...
3. Copy it as a Curl command (or whatever)
4. Reverse engineer that based on the [Google Play In-App Review API](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review)

Essentially, you need to page through the reviews by updating the pageToken query string parameter from each previous page. It starts empty but is the last thing in the page data, about 230 characters of base64-looking stuff.

The JSON keys are all numbers, but it's probably easy enough to backmap them.